# Eclipse default system web browser

Tags: linux, eclipse, browser

Using the Eclipse SDK under Linux, there's an entry in the list of "External web browsers" for "Default system web browser".  How is this default determined?

I set up and selected an entry that calls my own version of `xdg-open` which is just a wrapper to launch Chromium.  But, when I launched a project from the GWT plugin, it defaulted back to "Default system web browser".

I don't use a major desktop environment (neither GNOME nor KDE), so I'm unsure how any default would be set.  But it would be nicer to set this globally and avoid per-application (or per-plugin) configuration in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up source diving.  I wrote and stepped into a simple Eclipse Application that only gets the default browser the way Eclipse (the IDE) itself does ([in org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.SystemBrowserInstance](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.ui.browser/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/browser/SystemBrowserInstance.java?view=markup#l31)):

```
Program.findProgram("html")
```

Turns out Eclipse identifies my "desktop" as [DESKTOP_GIO](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT%20Program/gtk/org/eclipse/swt/program/Program.java?view=markup#l59), because I have the [GIO library](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.29/) installed as part of some GNOME dependency.  Because it ID's me as such it calls this libgio function:

```
g_app_info_get_default_for_type("text/html", false)
```

[According to the docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.29/ch03.html), GIO applications use the X Desktop Group (XDG) "standard" [Shared MIME-info Database](http://freedesktop.org/Standards/shared-mime-info-spec) to find applications that support a given MIME type.

In my case, I've never registered any application as the default handler for text/html, but Eclipse simply chooses the first one returned (which happens to be `winebrowser`, since it has a `wine-extension-html.desktop` entry in my `~/.local/share/applications/` directory).

In the end I used:

```
desktop-file-install \
    --rebuild-mime-info-cache \
    --dir ~/.local/share/applications \
    custom-script.desktop
```

to add a desktop entry for my custom script, and:

```
xdg-mime default custom-script.desktop text/html
```

to set it as the default for "html" files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a system that has the `update-alternatives` command, try to see what `update-alternatives --display x-www-browser` gives you - it defines what the default web browser is. use `update-alternatives --config x-www-browser` to set it to a specific program.

Comment: My system did have that command, which is odd, since it doesn't generally use an 'alternatives'-style system.  (Gentoo uses 'eselect' for similar purposes, but doesn't have a category for web browser.)  The actual solution was a bit more complicated, as I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I thought I would add what worked for me. I am running Gnome Classic on Debian Wheezy and installed Chromium.

I tried the update-alternatives approach to change the system-wide defaults from Iceweasel to Chromium:

```
update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
```

but Eclipse was still picking up Iceweasel. I then edited /etc/gnome/defaults.list to replace each instance of 'iceweasel.desktop' to 'chromium.desktop'.

I logged out and back in again, to be sure I get the new defaults, and this time Eclipse used the system browser, Chromium.